# AWS step function stuck in RUNNABLE state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, netflix-metaflow

[image: state machine]

I am using metaflow to define my state machine and push this to AWS step function. When I run this state machine my step is stuck at RUNNABLE step. I have used cloudformation template to setup AWS. For testing I have only these steps in my flow i.e., start, test and end. All 3 steps only contains a print statement and nothing else. I got to know that RUNNABLE meant that the task is pending in the queue, waiting for a suitable instance to
become available. [image] What could be the potential reason for this?

Comment: Try other compute ressources. On eu-central-1 I had to choose m5 instances instead of c4 or t3.